# Is it possible to wrap Group Panel in other kind of Panels in Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm wondering if is it possible to wrap in my main `Group Panel` in other kind of panels ?. Actually i can do it with code but i want to deal with it only from Scene Builder to arrange components more easily. For example you can see a simple code section of how i manage to wrap my main `Group Panel` in `Boder Pane`.

```
// My main panel which initialized automatically to Group Panel
rootPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Risk3.fxml"));

FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();

//Text Box 1
TextArea countryInfoText = new TextArea();
countryInfoText.setPrefWidth(100.0);
countryInfoText.maxWidth(100.0);

flowPane.getChildren().add(countryInfoText);
flowPane.setPrefWidth(countryInfoText.getPrefWidth());

BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
borderPane.setCenter(rootPane);
borderPane.setLeft(flowPane);

scene = new Scene(borderPane);

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

but Scene Builder doesnt let me wrap this `root` (or Group Panel in other words) in other Panels. You can see the snapshot below as an example.

[image]

Hope i had been clear to you and i will appreciate a lot for every response. So thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys i made it. The trick is you have to wrap the panel with changing the source code of `fxml` file. So i included the line

```
<BorderPane id="BorderPaneDocument" fx:id="mainPanel" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.RiskControllerClass">
  <center>
<Group>
.
.
</Group>
</center>
</BorderPane>
```

which Group was the main panel i wanted to wrap in BorderPane. So i created a Border Panel in fxml file and put the group panel on center of Border Pane. It works perfectly with this way and also i can modify every part from Scene Builder.